# Codeigniter: 404 page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

i created a folder insider controller's folder called admin and created a controller user as attached

[image]

this is how i am trying to access my User class in

```
http://localhost/site/admin/user/login
```

but its giving me 404 error page not found , i tried die() inside constructor to see if any views are missing or something else but still i get the same error.

i tried both User and user for accessing this but it did not work . Please help me to sort it out if i move same class outside admin folder it works fine .

Comment: try to access your controller on
http://localhost/site/index.php/admin/user/login

Comment: yeah it worked but how do i remove this index.php

Comment: I have added .htaccess code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can remove index.php from url using .htaccess file on your root directory

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file in your codeigniter root directory, in your case it's '/site' and add the below code in the file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the correct path in routes.php

Example:

```
$route['admin/user/(:any)'] = 'admin/user/$1';
$route['home/(:any)'] = 'home/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```